# Mail command limit

Tags: email, msmtp

I configured swatch to send alerts about threats through "mail" command. The problem is that it is sending me many same alerts, for example while I'm testing ping I can get like 8 e-mails etc.
Does anyone know how to limit amount of mails being sended about one alert?

Comment: `man swatch`, look for `threshold` and `limit`. I don't use `swatch` but it seems this should do what you want.